# How to pass the UsernameToken in header of SOAP Webservice with prefix asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, security, soap, usernametoken

Here is my Security xml that i need to pass from the header:
NOTE: I got this xml from the SOAP UI.

```html
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" 
 xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-9CCC0D29DF7BE6DFA8148905246588216">
   <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
   <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mypassword</wsse:Password>
   <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">zLncBYSL5VP8OMQNuesHlg==</wsse:Nonce>
   <wsu:Created>2017-03-09T09:41:05.882Z</wsu:Created>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```